# java Stack Searching

Tags: java, stack

I have a stack with objects like :

```
barcode \t date \t some_action
```

For example :

```
IP400H24 \t 20130527163520 \t in
```

Date is in form yyyymmddhhmmss

I want to take the first element of the stack and search the stack until I find for the first time, another object with the same barcode.

I am trying something but it is not correct :

```
// Get the barcode from the first object
String line = lifo.pop().toString().split("\t);
String barcode = line[0];
// Search for that barcode

while(!lifo.empty()) {
    String next_line = lifo.pop().toString().split("\t);
    String next_barcode = next_line[0];

    if (next_barcode.equals(barcode))
        //FOUND IT
    else
        //NOT FOUND
}
```

What is wrong with that?

> You are right.. I declare the sentence wrong.. I maybe need a break..
>   Thank you for you answers...

Comment: You should escape the \

Comment: Java's an object-oriented language.  I'd write a Barcode object to encapsulate that stuff together and put that on the stack instead of a tab-delimited string.  And I'd create a Stack<T> interface as the basis for the stack.

Answer (score 1):

**Using regex to match**

Try this regex:

```
IP400H24 \\t \d+ \\t [a-z]+
```

You can replace `IP400H24` with `barcode` using concatenation:

```
String matcher = barcode += "\\t \d+ \\t [a-z]+";
```

You can use this with `next_line.matches()`, example given:

```
if(next_line.matches(barcode + "\\t \d+ \\t [a-z]+")) {

}
```

**Related error**

Note that there's an error in retreiving the line:

```
String line = lifo.pop().toString().split("\t);
```

Should be

```
String line = lifo.pop().toString().split("\\t");
```